Does $L^p$ convergence preserve the $L^1 $ norm of the sequence
I have the following question which I could not figure out an answer for.
Suppose you have a sequence of non-negative functions $f_n$ in $L^p(U)$ with $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ bounded, $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, such that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\|f_n\|_1 = C$ for some uniform constant $C>0$.
Suppose $f_n \to f$ strongly (or weakly along subsequence) in some $L^p$. Can we conclude that $\|f\|_1 = C$?
I think that this amounts to showing that such a set of $f_n$ with $\|f_n\|_1 = C$ is closed. But I don't know what is the way for showing it. But perhaps there is an even easier way. Any ideas?

What is $U$ here? Finite or infinite measure?

Yes it is a bounded set.

Two things. First, convergence in $L^{p}$ for $1\leq p\leq \infty$ does not imply convergence in $L^{1}$ in case the measure space is not finite. In case the measure space is finite, then $\bigg|||f_{n}||{L^{1}}-||f||{L^{1}}\bigg|\leq ||f_{n}-f||{L^{1}}\leq C||f{n}-f||_{L^{p}}$ and the RHS goes to $0$. The $C$ is determined by Holder's inequality in case the measure space is finite.

If $\mu(U)$ is finite - yes, just by the fact $\|f\|_1 = \int f \cdot \operatorname{sign}(f)\, d\mu = \|f\|_p \cdot \mu(U)^\frac{p}{p - 1}$, so convergence in $L_p$ implies convergence in $L_1$.
Otherwise - no. Let $f_n$ be $\frac{1}{n}$ on set of measure $n$ - then $\|f_n\|_p = \sqrt[p]{n^{-p + 1}} \to 0$, thus $f_n \to_p 0$.

Thanks. But I don't see how this answers my question. I know there is a convergence in $L^1$ but I am asking about whether the the norm of the limit is preserved under the strong and weak covnergneces.

@Morcus See my comment.

@Morcus convergence in normed space implies convergence of norms, as $||f| - |f_n| |\leq  |f_n - f| \to 0$ (from triangle inequality).
